# bug in the console of google chrome

Tags: json, google-chrome

i try to print some JSON data from javascript function , but the problem is , the console ( from developer tools of google chrome ) show me one item with id ,but when i open this item i get another id , so where is the true id, this ( 0-0-0-0-0 when i open the item) [image: this] or this (0 when the item is closed) : [image]